# fixed background image on a sticky position div

Tags: html, css

I wanted to create an effect that looks something like this:

Desired effect:
[image]

I used a sticky div for creating the header rectangle and tried setting background-attachment to fixed but that's not working because the background gets fixed to the div which is moving. Does anybody know how can I implement this?

This is my css currently:

```
.headerdiv {
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
    height: 200px;
    background-image: url(res/header-bg.png);
    background-attachment: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    text-align: center;
    color: white; 
}
```

and my html:

```
<div class="headerdiv">
    <img class="logoimg"  src="res/logo.png"></img>
</div>
```

Comment: Please show us what did you try by posting your code. It helps to understand what you are trying to do and what difficulties you are facing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're going to need javascript to do this.  [Here's an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59512929/1195615) to a similar question.  In your case, you'll need to affect the `background-position` of the element instead of `top`;

If you need further assistance, throw your code in a snippet and I'll edit my answer to be more specific to your situation.

**Edit:** Here's an updated fiddle that should give you what you're after.

https://jsfiddle.net/h9vbmc8x/

Comment: Thank you very much! It worked like a charm. But I have one final question if you don't mind, Is there any easy way to make the header background image stick at the bottom instead of repeating? Or do I add something like if(y < -whateverMaxIs) { y = -whateverMaxIs; } ?